# Why does plim converge to expected value?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, regression, linear-regression

I have the following equation from some linear regression model where $x_i$ and $u_i$ are random variables:
$$
b=β+(\sum^N_{i=1}x_i x_i')^{-1} \sum^N_{i=1}x_iu_iγ 
$$
after applying $plim$ to the equation, my textbook tells me that we get:

$$
plim\ b=β+ (\sum^N_{i=1}x_i x_i')^{-1}E\{x_iu_i\}γ 
$$

while the first part of the equation is clear to me I don't understand how the $plim$ of $\sum^N_{i=1}x_iu_iγ $ converges to $E\{x_iu_i\}γ $.

My intuition tells for convergence to the expected value we (actually) need an extra factor of $1/N$ as in:
$$
plim \frac{1}{N}\sum^N_{i=1}x_iu_iγ = E\{x_iu_i\}γ 
$$

What am I getting wrong about the plim here?

Comment: Never seen the word "plim"... Could you explain what it is ?

Comment: plim is short for probability limit or convergence in probability.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Notation $b\overset{pr.}{\to} \frac1N...$ (`b\overset{pr.}{\to} \frac1N...`) would "probably" be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be
\begin{align}
(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i x_i^T)^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i u_i \gamma &= 
\frac{N}{N}(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i x_i^T)^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i u_i \gamma \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i x_i^T\right)^{-1} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i u_i \gamma\\
&\to
\left(E\left[x_i x_i^T\right]\right)^{-1} E\left[ x_i u_i\right]\gamma
\end{align}
where $\to$ stands for convergence in probability.